# Golang не видит функцию из пакета main

Tags: golang

Golang 1.10 установлен в D:\Program Files\Go

GOROOT D:\Program Files\Go

GOPATH D:\Program Files\Go\Projects

Тестовый проект находится в D:\Program Files\Go\Projects\src\tmp

Код main.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("tmp1")
    tmp()
}
```

Файл tmp.go находится в том же каталоге что и main.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func tmp()  {
    fmt.Println("tmp2")
}
```

При запуске команды go run main.go получаю ошибку:

> ## command-line-arguments
>
> .\main.go:7:2: undefined: tmp

Почему не отрабатывает вызов функции tmp() ? Ведь main.go и tmp.go находятся в одном каталоге и одном пакете. Причем go build отрабатывает без проблем.

Answer (score 6):

Для go run следует передавать все файлы пакета main, разделяя их пробелом:

```
go run main.go tmp.go
```

Идейно go run предназначен для быстрого запуска маленьких программ из одного файла, во всех остальных случаях используйте go build/install.