# Golang:не могу использовать дургие пакеты

Tags: golang

В папке проекта находятся 3 файла:

1. main.go  (package main)
2. crm.go   (package crm)
3. token.go (package token)

Я хочу в файле main.go реализовать запуск функций из оставшихся двух пакетов. Соответственно, в файле **main.go**  я пишу:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "token.go" //token, или полный путь  к файлу

func main(){
    fmt.Println("1");
}
```

При запуске командой:

> go run main.go

Получаю ошибку:

> cannot find package "token.go" in any of:
>           C:\Go\src\token.go (from $GOROOT)
>           C:\Users\UserName\go\src\token.go (from $GOPATH)
>   Я пробовал разными способами указывать путь к фаулу **token.go**

**Как в моем случае правильно подключать другие GO-файлы?**

Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Golang не видит функцию из пакета main](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796809/golang-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-main)

Comment: Пакет - это директорий. В одном и том же директории может находиться только один пакет и тесты к нему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте
1. в token.go тоже поставить package main
2. в main.go убрать импорт token
3. просто обращаться к функциям в token.go